# Apache allow access to symlink

Tags: apache-http-server, symbolic-link

Please help me figure this out, I'm out of options what to even google. No idea why this apache configuration is not working as I expected.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/x/frontend/www"
        ServerName test.dev
        Alias /uploads "/var/www/x/common/uploads"
        <Directory "/var/www/x/frontend/www">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory "/var/www/x/common/uploads">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all   
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when accessing http://test.dev/uploads/something, I get 403 Forbidden. In apache error log:

> "AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
>   /var/www/x/common/uploads/something"

`/var/www/x/common/uploads/something` is a symbolic link to `/home/myusername/something`, which is a remote folder mounted with sshfs.

`/home/myusername/something` has 755 permissions and everything inside it has 777 permissions.

Comment: First find out, if it is link-related or permission-related: Use `Alias /uploads "/home/myusername/something"` with a fitting `<Direcotry>` directive, retry and post results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have two guesses:

1. /home/myusername has 750 permissions, so Apache is not able to access subdirectories
2. The mounted directory is still not accessible for other users (FUSE does it by default), try `sshfs -o allow_other` to fix that.

Anyway, you need to determine whether it is something wrong with the Apache configuration or the Apache server can't access the files. Try to do `sudo -u www-data ls /var/www/x/common/uploads/something` (change the `www-data` to a user under which the apache is running on your system). If you get an error, you need to fix permissions somewhere, otherwise there is something wrong with the configuration.

Comment: Turns out it was a permission problem (option 2 helped). Thanks! :)